# WC API, Invalid parameter(s): role

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

When I run this request I get a Invalid parameter error.

```
curl http://localhost/wp-json/wc/v3/customers -u user:pass
```

Error:

```
{"code":"rest_invalid_param","message":"Invalid parameter(s): role","data":
{"status":400,"params":{"role":"role is not one of all, administrator, shop_manager, retail, member, wholesale."}}}%
```

I tracked the cause of it at
    `html/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-request.php`

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/91da29d9afaa664eb84e1261ebb916b18a362aa9/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-request.php#L803-L812

The request works fine after I comment out the `WP_Error`. After I deactivated other woocommerce plugins I still get this error. Any ideas?

Comment: It's working perfectly fine in my website. I think you need enable to WooCommerce REST API or try revoking the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. It is looking for the role with the value `customer`. I delete it. This error goes away after I created a customer role.